# Matplotlib: Rotate an ellipse in 3D issue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a simple ellipse projected to 3D from 2D.

```
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d    
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
p= Ellipse(xy=(6000,7000), width=2000, height=150,edgecolor='b',  fc='b', lw=2)
ax.add_patch(p)
art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=5000, zdir="x")
ax.set_xlim(0, 12500)
ax.set_ylim(0, 12500)
ax.set_zlim(6500, 7600)
plt.show()
```

The result is shown below

[image]

How do I try and rotate the ellipse in 3D in the xy plane. The "angle" argument in ellipse seems to revolve the ellipse as not rotate with an azimuth. Any pointers?

Comment: I don't know of any easy way to achieve this (that does not mean, there is none). Be reminded that matplotlib is a 2D plotting library that was extended into 3D plotting. It is no a substitute for programs like Mayavi. But here is a solution to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18228966/8881141

Comment: Thanks.. I was able to solve this using the solution you pointed to ..