# Plot 4D data and further extract few slices at specific Z

Tags: python, matplotlib, 4d

I have 4 columns (longitude, latitude, depth (Km), Value) and I want to plot in python and later extract some slices at specific depth from this plot.

Here is my try but I do not know how to further plot a few slices (e.g at depth of 2,4 and 5 Km).

very first part of Input file:

```
104.38 29.35 1 -0.0231
104.38 29.35 -0.07 0.02001
104.38 29.35 -1.14 -0.0052
104.38 29.35 -2.21 -0.0125
104.38 29.35 -3.28 -0.0096
104.38 29.35 -4.35 0.00230
104.38 29.35 -5.42 0.03000
104.38 29.35 -6.5 0.06930
104.38 29.382 1 0
104.38 29.382 -0.07 0.00623
104.38 29.382 -1.14 -0.0330
104.38 29.382 -2.21 0.02587
104.38 29.382 -3.28 0.02292
104.38 29.382 -4.35 0.01601
104.38 29.382 -5.42 0.01902
104.38 29.382 -6.5 -0.0055
104.38 29.414 1 0.00475
104.38 29.414 -0.07 0.01204
104.38 29.414 -1.14 0.02220
104.38 29.414 -2.21 0.02166
```

I tried this to plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

points = np.loadtxt("Q_12_Degrees_Hz.txt",delimiter=',')
lon = points[:,0]
lat = points[:,1]
depth = points[:,2]
V = points[:,3]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9), dpi=80)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.view_init(55,60)

V = V/ V.max().max()

ax.plot_trisurf(lon,lat,depth,facecolors=plt.cm.jet(V))
title("3-D")
ax.set_xlabel("Longitude [degrees]")
ax.set_ylabel("Latitude [degrees]")
ax.set_zlabel("Depth [km]")
```

P.S: really do not know why facecolor does not work

Output:

[image]

Expected Ideal Output:

[image]

Comment: Hey Aqeel, could you specify better the axis/slices of your plot? X and Y are clear, Z, seems to be depth; "V" I guess is just for coloring. But it is not clear how do you want to see it? Just slices? No (3D) surface?

Comment: yes you are right. I will update the question. it will be not 3D surface but values at specific depth (Z) e.g. inspect the values at 2 Km so I think it should be flat

Comment: The very first part of the input file is not enough for us to work with, as a matter of fact it throws an error. The reason is the longitude is the same for all points... We are unable to obtain your first figure.

Comment: @Davide_sd  this is just a part of the data. In this, values are calculated at every longitude and latitude at each depth but values are different in each pair. Data range is : Longitude (104,105), latitude (29.36,29.64) and depth (1,-6)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here, in the official docs examples:

- *"Draw flat objects in 3D plot"*: https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/gallery/mplot3d/pathpatch3d.html

In particular, I would start (understanding) from the call(s) [art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d.html). Looks suggestive.

Also, check this other answer:

- [How can matplotlib 2D patches be transformed to 3D with arbitrary normals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228966/how-can-matplotlib-2d-patches-be-transformed-to-3d-with-arbitrary-normals)