# Add external objects within matplotlib/plotly 3d plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I would like to know, how can I add or draw 3d model like for example those rectangular frames(gates), to a 3D plot in `matplotlib` or in `plotly`. I have searched for that quite for a long time, but I could not find a way that will allow me to do that. [image] It would be great to achieve that as one object not as points(preferrably), so that I can arrange their placement and integration with existing drawing smoothly. But any help you could provide to achieve that is truly appreciated

Comment: If you know how to do this "as points", then just write a function to do this with your desired parameters. In any case, please provide a [mre] and clearly explain the desired logic.

Comment: I do not know how to do that as points, that is why I wrote "But any help you could provide to achieve that is truly appreciated". What I want to achieve is very clear I suppose, there is no minimal working example, the task itself is somehow atomic, either I know how to do it, or no, and I don't, that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the modified version of [pathpatch_2d_to_3d](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33213658/3715182), e.g. in this way:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
# this library contains functions taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33213658/3715182
from special_pathpatch_2d_to_3d import pathpatch_2d_to_3d, pathpatch_translate

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# make some parametric curve
theta = np.linspace(-1 * np.pi, 1 * np.pi, 20)
Z = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
r = Z**2 + 1
X = r * np.sin(theta)
Y = r * np.cos(theta)
ax.plot(X, Y, Z, color='blue', marker='o')

# draw 3D patches around all the curve points but the last one
for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(zip(X[:-1], Y[:-1], Z[:-1])):
    # add a 2D patch at the origin
    p = Circle((0, 0), 0.2, facecolor='none', edgecolor='red')
    ax.add_patch(p)
    # transform it into a 3D patch at the origin, reorienting it to follow the current direction of the curve
    normal = (X[i+1] - x, Y[i+1] - y, Z[i+1] - z)
    pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=0, normal=normal)
    # place the patch at the current curve coordinate
    pathpatch_translate(p, (x, y, z))

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but the idea is that those should be just surfaces independent from the path

Comment: Surely you can place those surfaces independently, wherever you want on a plot with already existing curves, other surfaces, etc. For example, in the code from my answer I could add those circle patches anywhere, not necessarily along the curve. I did it that way just because I thought it was exactly what you needed.

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to avoid using patches, but they seem to be the best option for drawing such kind of things, in my opinion, since they fulfill your original requirement to have them as objects, not as points. Alternatively, you can draw them somehow with `plot_surface`, on the axis of an already existing plot.

Comment: Thank you, but from the image I have in my question, the object does not seem to be drawn by standard matplot methods, I assume it has been imported or so, would be glad if you can provide guidence on how to achieve similar result to the image shown in my question